# Structure Flask-Restful API to use SQLAlchemy

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

So I'm trying to make an API, using Flask-Restful, but all the examples I find put everything into one app.py file. I found information in the [Flask-Restful docs](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.2/intermediate-usage.html#project-structure) explaining how to structure your API, but it doesn't include anything for using a database. I've posted what I've come up with, and it works if I hard-code some data, but when I import the `db` into `users.py` I get an error `ImportError: cannot import name 'db'`. So, what is the best way to structure an API to bring in your data from a database?

**Structure**

```
myapi
    run.py
    api
        __init__.py
        resources
            __init__.py
            user.py
```

**myapi/run.py**

```
from api import app
app.run()
```

**myapi/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.restful import Api
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from api.resources.user import User

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://localhost/myapi'

api = Api(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

api.add_resource(User, '/user')
```

**../resources/user.py**

```
from flask.ext.restful import Resource
from api import db


class User(Resource, db.Model):
    def get(self):
        return {'class': 'user', 'first': 'john', 'last': 'doe'}
```

Comment: What's in api? Show us.

Comment: @RobertMoskal oh that's a folder

Comment: your db is in `__init__`, but you import it from `api` in `user.py`

Comment: yes, like corvid said, your issue is from api in user.py, should be from app import db

Answer (score 3):

Move your resource/model import to below where you assign the `db` variable (since those modules/scripts rely on the db already being instantiated):

**myapi/api/__init__.py**

```python
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.restful import Api
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://localhost/myapi'

api = Api(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from api.resources.user import User

api.add_resource(User, '/user')
```

Comment: Key point is notice is that `from api.resources.user import User` is **after** `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem and it had me stumped for longer than I care to admit. Looks like this is the same problem here so despite the age of the question I'll give an answer in the hope that I can save someone else some time. The problem here is actually an order-of-packages thing. The db in the main init has to be instantiated before the user class is imported, because this imports the db itself. I think that this is a trap that a lot of people fall into because one's immediate reflex is to put all the package loaders at the top of the file - sadly, in this case, it doesn't work and you end up chasing your tail for ages...